# How do I make it so that only letters and spaces can be entered into a textbox in VB?

Tags: vb.net

All the letters in the alphabet.

Is it possible to automatically capitalize the first letter?

I've been using this code for a different program but it only allows you to enter letters. I'm trying to adapt it.

```
Private Sub LettersOnly(ByRef Character As Char)
    ' Purpose: Validate character input: letters and control keys only
    If Char.IsLetter(Character) = False And Char.IsControl(Character) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Letters only.", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        ' Stop invalid character appearing in field
        Character = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Windows Forms, try this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If (Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> " "c) Then e.Handled = True
    If (DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text.Length = 0) Then e.KeyChar = Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at [I only want letter to be accepted into the textbox on vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161634/i-only-want-letter-to-be-accepted-into-the-textbox-on-vb-net) .  It uses regular expressions to validate.
2. Look at FilteredTextBoxExtender.  (ASP ONLY)
3. Look at Field Validators in ASPX.  There are regex capable ones. (ASP ONLY)

Note sure if you are referring to Win or Web OFmrs.